# asp.net mobile/desktop site toggle button, switching masterpage, but styles "stuck"

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, master-pages, switch-statement

## Summary

I'm having style issues when flipping master pages via a button event in asp.net 4.0. The new master switches, but the css from the old master remains. I don't understand how this could happen as the styles are defined within the head of the old master, and i can clearly see via the markup the new master is being displayed with whats supposed to be a totally different set of styles. Also, viewing source shows all the new css declarations in the head. How can i get this to "refresh" or "reload"?

## Some details

I'm implementing a mobile version of my asp.net site. If a mobile device is detected i set a cookie and switch the master page in the preinit to a mobile friendly one. This works fine:

```
protected virtual void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsMobile)
        this.Page.MasterPageFile = "m-" + this.Page.MasterPageFile;
}
```

I have a "full site" button at the bottom that allows you to flip back and forth between the mobile and desktop view. When clicking it, i change the value in the cookie. Then when the page redirects to itself, the value is checked, and it gives the respective masterpage. This also "works", i can tell the right masterpage is rendering via markup. Except the styles from the mobile version remain even when the desktop master is being displayed. I did the redirect thinking it would prevent this.

```
// desktop/mobile site toggle button click event
protected void viewMobileButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie isMobileCookie = Cookies.snatchCookie("isMobile");

    if (bool.Parse(isMobileCookie.Value))
        Cookies.bakeCookie("isMobile", "false");
    else
        Cookies.bakeCookie("isMobile", "true");

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

This is the first time I've done anything like this, and not sure if i'm even going about it the right way, or how to debug from here. Thanks in advance for any help.

## Edit

Ok, so i figured out it's related to the JQuery Mobile Scripts. JQuery Mobile has this way of tying pages together. I don't fully understand it, i think they use it for page transitions, and it's preventing my new CSS from registering. When i turn it off, my masterpage flips fine with css included. I'm looking into a way to turn off JQuery Mobile before my redirect. Note sure how though yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being related to JQuery Mobile AJAX for page-transitions. JQuery Mobile does not load the head of the document on additional page requests after the first.

So when i'd switch the mobile master to the desktop master, the head of the document wouldn't load to bring in my styles. There are a few way's this can be fixed:

This way just turns off AJAX altogether, and fixes the problem, but then you can't benefit from it:

```
<form data-ajax="false">
```

This is a way to do it problematically, but remind you, it will not work via an event after initialization of JQuery Mobile, so again you can't benefit from it:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

The above two solutions i support could work if you redirected through a page first if you have to use an onclick event and an event handler.

A better solution is to add rel="external" to the link to tell JQM it's and outgoing link.

```
<a href="myself.com?mobile=true" rel="external" >
```

But because i couldn't run some code i wanted to in order to change the cookie, i had to pass a query string parameter, check it on the preinit, then set the cookie which my page also looks at on the preinit and flips the master.

Here's my full solution below in case someone is out there doing the exact same thing. Note because my website is using aliasing, i had to read Request.RawUrl and parse it myself since the Request.QueryString object did not contain the values i passed.

```
    // reusable function that parses a string in standard query string format(foo=bar&dave=awesome) into a Dictionary collection of key/value pairs
    // return the reference to the object, you have to assign it to a local un-instantiated name
    // will accept a full url, or just a query string
    protected Dictionary<string, string> parseQueryString(string url)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            // if the string is still a full url vs just the query string
            if (url.Contains("?"))
            {
                string[] urlArray = url.Split('?');
                url = urlArray[1]; // snip the non query string business away
            }

            string[] paramArray = url.Split('&');

            foreach (string param in paramArray)
            {
                if (param.Contains("="))
                {
                    int index = param.IndexOf('=');
                    d.Add(param.Substring(0, index), param.Substring(++index));
                }
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Then i just use my dictionary object to evaluate and rebuild my url with the opposite mobile value, dynamically setting the href on the toggle link. Some code is obviosuly left out, but for perspective, base._iPage.QueryStringParams hold my dictionary object that was returned, and base._iPage.IsMobile is just a bool property i also have via the page interface i use, that all my pages, and user controls, ect, can talk to.

```
        // get the left side fo the url, without querystrings
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[0]);

        // build link to self, preserving query strings, except flipping mobile value
        if (base._iPage.QueryStringParams.Count != 0)
        {
            if (base._iPage.QueryStringParams.ContainsKey("mobile"))
            {
                // set to opposite of current
                base._iPage.QueryStringParams["mobile"] = (!base._iPage.IsMobile).ToString();
            }

            int count = 0;
            url.Append('?');

            // loop through query string params, and add them back on
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in base._iPage.QueryStringParams)
            {
                count++;
                url.Append(item.Key + "=" + item.Value + (count == base._iPage.QueryStringParams.Count ? "" : "&" )); 
            }
        }

        // assign rebuild url to href of toggle link
        viewMobileButton.HRef = url.ToString();
    }
```

Then on my pageinit this is where i actually check, first the quesry string, then the cookie, if neither of those are present, i run my mobile detection method, and set a cookie, and my interface bool property for easy access to conditionals that depends on it.

```
        QueryStringParams = base.parseQueryString(Request.RawUrl);

        if (QueryStringParams.ContainsKey("mobile") ? QueryStringParams["mobile"].ToLower().Equals("true") : false)
        {
            Cookies.bakeCookie("isMobile", "true"); // create a cookie
            IsMobile = true;
        }
        else if (QueryStringParams.ContainsKey("mobile") ? QueryStringParams["mobile"].ToLower().Equals("false") : false)
        {
            Cookies.bakeCookie("isMobile", "false"); // create a cookie
            IsMobile = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsMobile = base.mobileDetection();
        }

        if (IsMobile)
            this.Page.MasterPageFile = "m-" + this.Page.MasterPageFile;
    }
```